# Binding width in UWP is not working, how can I update width?

Tags: uwp, uwp-xaml, xamarin.uwp

I have used ListView and observable collection, and below is data template of that one.
I have binded the width of Rectangle to the relative panel but it is not working

```
<DataTemplate>
     <RelativePanel x:Name="Tab" SizeChanged="{x:Bind Tab_SizeChanged}">
        <StackPanel>
            <TextBox Text="{Binding TabName, Mode=TwoWay}">
            </TextBox>
        </StackPanel>
        <Rectangle Fill="{Binding Color}" RelativePanel.AlignBottomWithPanel="True" Width="{Binding ElementName=Tab,Path=Width}">
        </Rectangle>
    </RelativePanel></DataTemplate>
```

And I have tried this also `Width="{Binding RectWidth}"` and I am updating the `RectWidth` when the relative panel size changes

code behind file looks like this

```
    public double RectWidth{get;set;}
    public void Tab_SizeChanged(object sender, SizeChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        RectWidth = e.NewSize.Width;
    }
```

neither of them are working.

Comment: Does the `Rectange` have a `Height`? What's the difference between `RectWidth` and `TabColorRectWidth`? Do you implemement `INotifyPropertyChanged` in the right place?

Comment: @mm8 yes I did set height as 4 and, as I said I've used ListView with ObservableCollection so no need of INotifyPropertyChanged, TabColorRectWidth is Typo I've updated the question

Comment: You still need to implement `INotifyPropertyChanged` to notify the view of the update of the source property. The collection type which happens to store the reference to the object has nothing to do with this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Binding to a source property that you set dynamically should work assuming you implement `INotifyPropertyChanged` and raise the `PropertyChanged` event to notify the view of the update.

But since you already handle the `SizeChanged` event for the `Panel`, you could set the `Width` of the `Rectangle` directly in the handler:

```
public void Tab_SizeChanged(object sender, SizeChangedEventArgs e)
{
    RelativePanel panel = (RelativePanel)sender;
    Rectangle rectangle = panel.Children[1] as Rectangle;
    if (rectangle != null)
        rectangle.Width = e.NewSize.Width;
}
```

Comment: thanks, I thought using `ObservableCollection` is enough, when I used `INotifyPropertyChanged` it worked.